# Powershell - test Real access for an USER

Tags: powershell, acl, ntfs, rights

I need to test if user has realy access to a folder (Read, Write, Delete), not juste the NTFS Rights.

I use Start-process whit user credential

Answer (score 1):

I write a script for this, it avalaible on multi AD forest, with local, UNC and DFS paths

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Teste les droits reel dans un dossier
    .DESCRIPTION
        Tente d'ecrire un fichier dans la destination specifiée en tant que NtAccountName
    .PARAMETER Path
        FQDN du dossier a tester
        ex : '\\open.adds\RPannuzzo$\Pannuzzolk\Donnees\Scans'
    .PARAMETER NtaccountName
        Nom d'utilisateur complet
        ex : 'contoso\JhonDoe'
    .EXAMPLE
        .\Test-RealAccess.ps1 -path 'D:\repertoire
    .EXAMPLE
        .\Test-RealAccess.ps1 '\\open.adds\Rshare$\Pathlk\Data' -ntAccountName 'contoso\JhonDoe'

        le mdp vous sera demandé, une seule fois et sera enregistre dans la registry
    .NOTES
        Alopez 2016
        Em@il : alban.lopez ON gmail.com
#>
#requires -version 3

param(
    [string[]]$paths = '\\Contoso.adds\Share$\Target\Data',
    $ntAccountName = 'contoso\JhonDoe'
)


$version = '0.53 / Test Read,Write,Supp.'
$source = "Script Test d'access reel (alopez)"

function Get-CredentialByRegistry ($ntAccountName) {
    $regKey = "HKCU:\Software\Pass\$ntAccountName"

    # voir le mdp
    # [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR(((Get-ItemProperty $regKey -Name SecurePass).SecurePass | convertto-securestring)))
    if( !(Get-ItemProperty $regKey -Name SecurePass -ea 0).SecurePass) {
        # on demande et on enregistre le mdp
        new-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Pass" -EA 0 | out-null
        new-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Pass\$($ntAccountName.split('\')[0])" -EA 0 | out-null
        new-Item -Path $regKey -EA 0 | out-null
        $WinCredential = Get-Credential -UserName "$ntAccountName" -Message "Identifiant de connexion : $ntAccountName`nPour les tests de validation"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -name SecurePass -value ($WinCredential.GetNetworkCredential().securePassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString)
    }

    return new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist @("$NtAccountName",((Get-ItemProperty $regKey -Name SecurePass -ea 0).SecurePass | convertto-securestring))
}

$ACL = @()

$ACL = foreach ($path in $paths) {
    $access = $null
    Remove-Item "$path\test-RW.txt","$path\test-ForRead.txt",'.\access.txt','.\error.txt' -Force -ea 0 | out-null
    start-sleep -s 2
    try{
        'Readable' | Set-Content "$path\test-ForRead.txt" -Force -ea stop | out-null
        write-host " Droits pour " -nonewline -fore blue -back White
        write-host "$ntAccountName" -nonewline -fore darkgreen -back White
        write-host " dans [" -nonewline -fore blue -back White
            write-host "$path" -fore magenta -nonewline -back White
                write-host '] : '.padright(80-$ntAccountName.length-$path.length) -nonewline -fore blue -back White
        try{
            (Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -Credential (Get-CredentialByRegistry $ntAccountName -PassThru) "powershell.exe" -RedirectStandardOutput '.\access.txt' -RedirectStandardError '.\error.txt' `
            -ArgumentList "
            whoami | Set-Content '$path\test-RW.txt' -ea Continue;
            start-sleep -s 1;

            if ((get-content '$path\test-ForRead.txt' -ea Continue) -like 'Readable') {
                'R';
            };

            if ((get-content '$path\test-RW.txt' -ea Continue) -like `$(whoami)) {
                'W';
            };

            Remove-Item '$path\test-ForRead.txt' -ea Continue;
            start-sleep -s 1;
            if (!(Test-Path '$path\test-ForRead.txt' -ea Continue)) {
                'S';
            };
            " `
            -ea SilentlyContinue)
        } catch {
            # l'execution "en tant que" retourne toujours une erreur, meme si tout fonctionne
        }
        start-sleep -s 5;
        $access = (get-content '.\access.txt') -join('')
        if ($access -clike 'RWS') {
            write-host "$access".padleft(10).padright(16) -fore Black -back Green
        } elseif ($access.length -ge 1) {
            write-host "$access".padleft(10).padright(16) -fore DarkGreen -back Yellow
        } else {
            write-host "      [ ! ]     " -fore White -back Red
        }
    } catch {
        write-host "`n`tVous n'avez pas acces a [ " -fore White -back Red -nonewline
        write-host "$path" -fore White -back magenta -nonewline
        write-host " ] ! Impossible de faire le test !".padright(54) -fore White -back Red
    }
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            'path' = $path
            'ntAccountName' = $ntAccountName
            'Read' = ($access -clike '*R*')
            'Write' = ($access -clike '*W*')
            'Supp.' = ($access -clike '*S*')
            'Access' = $access 
        }
    Remove-Item "$path\test-RW.txt","$path\test-ForRead.txt" -Force -ea 0 | out-null
}

return $ACL
```